# reading and displaying video file frame by frame

Tags: matlab, video

I am newly working with Matlab. I want to read a video file and do some calculations every frame and display every frame. I wrote the following code but every time it only displays the first frame. can anybody please help.

```
mov=VideoReader('c:\vid\Akiyo.mp4');
nFrames=mov.NumberOfFrames;
for i=1:nFrames
  videoFrame=read(mov,i);
  imshow(videoFrame);

end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Note: `mmreader` API has been discontinued by MATLAB so prefer using `VideoReader`.

See comment by @Vivek.

I usually do this:

```
obj=mmreader('c:\vid\Akiyo.mp4');
nFrames=obj.NumberOfFrames;
for k=1:nFrames
    img=read(obj,k);
    figure(1),imshow(img,[]);
end
```

As far as your code is concerned, I saw MATLAB's documentation. You should do the things in following order:

```
mov=VideoReader('c:\vid\Akiyo.mp4');
vidFrames=read(mov);
nFrames=mov.NumberOfFrames;
for i=1:nFrames
   imshow(vidFrames(:,:,i),[]);  %frames are grayscale
end
```

Comment: Dear Parag, What is the main difference betwn the above and below code snippet. Actually the above code is working fine but not the below one. the below one only displays the first frame. thanks.

Comment: I will see in detail and get back to you.

Comment: the last method only displays the luma component of the first frame. The code should be `imshow(vidFrames(:,:,:,i));` This way you can read the luma and chroma component of each frame.

Comment: Just a word of caution: 'mmreader' API has been discontinued by MATLAB so prefer using 'VideoReader'.

Answer (score 1):

Function read() and the field NumberOfFrames() are now deprecated, Matlab suggests using

```
xyloObj = VideoReader(file);
vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;
vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;
mov = struct('cdata',zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, 3,'uint8'), 'colormap',[]);

while hasFrame(xyloObj)
    mov(k).cdata = readFrame(xyloObj,'native');     
end
```

In case you want to estimate a number of frames in the video, use `nFrames = floor(xyloObj.Duration) * floor(xyloObj.FrameRate);`

Answer (score 0):

Below suggested code is showing only one frame

```
imshow(vidFrames(:,:,i),[]);
```

I am doing following things to store each frame

```
obj = VideoReader('path/to/video/file');

for img = 1:obj.NumberOfFrames;
    filename = strcat('frame',num2str(img),'.jpg');
    b = read(obj,img);
    imwrite(b,filename);
end
```

This will store all the frames in your home directory.And yes, as also suggested by Vivek and Parag

> You need to use VideoReader as mmreader has been discontinued by
>   MATLAB.

Comment: There is no 'NumberOfFrames' field in VideoReader

Answer (score 0):

*=I was making a function to play any .avi file as a set of frames in a figure.  Here's what a did. A bit of a combo of what you've done, except my NumberOfFrames wasn't working: (noteL this also shows it in colour)

```
function play_video(filename)
% play_video  Play a video file
% play_video(filename) plays the video file specified by filename in a MATLAB Figure window.

figure
set(figure, 'Visible', 'on')
mov=VideoReader(filename);
vidFrames=read(mov);
duration = mov.Duration;
frame_rate = mov.FrameRate;
total_frames = duration .* frame_rate


for i=1:1:total_frames
   imshow(vidFrames(:, :, :, i), []);
   drawnow
end
```